# Потеря обработчиков событий после использования LINQ

Tags: c#, события, linq, observablecollection

Есть `ObservableCollection<string> mystrings`, которой я на старте приложения присваиваю значения, и делаю обработчик события `mystrings.CollectionChanged += mystrings_OnChange;`

Однако дальше мне нужно сделать выборку из этой коллекции, отсеить ненужные элементы, и удалить их из коллекции. Однако когда я делаю

```
mystrings = new ObservableCollection<string>(mystrings.Where(x => x ...));
```

То после этого у меня `mystrings` новый обьект, который "потерял" обработчики событий. Как правильнее с этим бороться?

Comment: ну так очевидно добавить обработчик снова

Comment: Это понятно, но не удобно. В том контексте будет крайне сложно достать обработчик заново. Может есть какой-нибудь способ копировать обработчики?

Comment: скопировать в коллекцию ту выборку которую ты сделал. не забудь посмотреть что будет с длинной

Comment: @dgzargo видимо это лучший вариант. Оформите, как ответ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Проблема `ObservableCollection` в том, что она не работает с диапазонами данных одновременно (добавить диапазон, удалить диапазон, заменить диапазон). [Предложение добавить диапазоны в API `ObservableCollection`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10752) ещё не реализовано и [не будет даже в .NET Core 3.x, так как команда WPF и так очень загружена](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10752#issuecomment-498404073) из-за того, что данное предложение может поломать WPF, который не умеет работать с изменением диапазона данных, а не одного элемента данных.

Поэтому вижу три возможности:

1. Пересоздать коллекцию, заново добавить обработчик события `CollectionChanged`. Вы так и сделали в своём вопросе.
2. Получить коллекцию элементов, которые нужно оставить, очистить `ObservableCollection` с помощью метода `Clear`, в цикле добавить в `ObservableCollection` нужные элементы через `Add`. Возможно, надо будет отключить обработчик `CollectionChanged` до `Clear` и цикла добавления, а затем подключить его заново после цикла.
3. Получить коллекцию элементов для удаления, в цикле удалить из `ObservableCollection` ненужные элементы через `Remove`. Возможно, надо будет отключить обработчик `CollectionChanged` до цикла удаления, а затем подключить его заново после цикла.

Comment: Подозреваю, что первый способ будет лучше остальных в части нагрузки на сборщик мусора.

Answer (score 4):

Возможно поможет моя библиотека [ObservableComputations](https://github.com/IgorBuchelnikov/ObservableComputations). Ваш код с использованием этой библиотеки будет выглядеть так:

```C#
ObservableCollection<string> filteredMystrings = mystrings.Filtering(x => x ...));
```

Чтобы этот код работал нужно чтобы mystrings был ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 3):

скопировать в коллекцию ту выборку которую ты сделал
не забудь посмотреть что будет с длинной

мой вариант:

```
oc.ClearItems();
foreach(l in enumerable){
    oc.InsertItem(l);
}
```

специально посмотрел в Microsoft.Docs. оба метода вызывают событие `CollectionChanged`

Comment: Ваш ответ тоже правильный. Но зачем использовать `InsertItem`, если у нас коллекция и так пустая, почему-бы не использовать просто `Add`?

Answer (score 2):

Реализация третьего варианта ответа [@Vadim Ovchinnikov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1001649/22836), но без создания временной коллекции.

```
//Использованы части кода из ответа @KuzCode

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var collection = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler = (obj, e) =>
    {                
        if (obj is ObservableCollection<int> coll)
        {
            Console.Write("items now: ");
            foreach (var item in coll)
                Console.Write(item + " ");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    };
    collection.CollectionChanged += handler;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) collection.Add(i);

    collection.RemoveNotMatched(t => t >= 5);
    collection.RemoveNotMatched(t => t >= 7, handler);
    Console.ReadKey();
}      

public static void RemoveNotMatched<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> coll
    , Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    for (int i = coll.Count()-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var item = coll[i];
        if (!predicate(item))
            coll.Remove(item);
    }            
}

public static void RemoveNotMatched<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> coll
    , Func<T, bool> predicate
    , NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler)
{
    coll.CollectionChanged -= handler;
    RemoveNotMatched(coll, predicate);
    coll.CollectionChanged += handler;
    handler(coll, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
}
```

Вывод

```
items now: 0
items now: 0 1
items now: 0 1 2
items now: 0 1 2 3
items now: 0 1 2 3 4
items now: 0 1 2 3 4 5
items now: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
items now: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
items now: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
items now: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
items now: 0 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9
items now: 0 1 2 5 6 7 8 9
items now: 0 1 5 6 7 8 9
items now: 0 5 6 7 8 9
items now: 5 6 7 8 9
items now: 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Я предлагаю, возможно, не самый быстрый по производительности способ, но он абсолютно практичен. Просто создайте функцию-расширение для коллекции **CopyFrom()**, которая принимает **List**, и добавьте все объекты из списка в вашу коллекцию.

Вот пример кода:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Rextester
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var collection = new ObservableCollection<int>();
            collection.CollectionChanged += (obj, e) => // добавляем событие
            {
                Console.Write("items now: ");
                foreach (var item in collection)
                    Console.Write(item + " ");
                Console.WriteLine();
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) collection.Add(i); // добавляем элементы
            collection.CopyFrom(collection.Where((item) => item >= 5).ToList()); //делаем выборку
        }

        public static void CopyFrom<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> coll, List<T> list)
        {
            coll.Clear();
            list.ForEach((item) => coll.Add(item));
        }
    }
}
```

И пример вывода:

```
items now: 0 
items now: 0 1 
items now: 0 1 2 
items now: 0 1 2 3 
items now: 0 1 2 3 4 
items now: 0 1 2 3 4 5 
items now: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
items now: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
items now: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
items now: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
items now: 
items now: 5 
items now: 5 6 
items now: 5 6 7 
items now: 5 6 7 8 
items now: 5 6 7 8 9
```